# Can I use the DirectX 11 SDK without a DirectX 11 card?

Tags: sdk, directx

If I write a DirectX 11 application using the DX11 SDK, and I don't have a DirectX card, will I be able to run the application?

I can't find the requirements for actually using the DX11 SDK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. What you are looking for is called [Direct3D feature levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). With this 
paradigm you can write an application with the features supported by your graphic card. Before  the creation of the D3D device you can query the card and find the feature level supported, then you use this level in the device creation.

Of course you cannot use the new features provided by DirectX 11 on your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial site](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-4-2) states that when setting up a device and swap chain, a D3D_DRIVER_TYPE of D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE can be used to allow DX11 features
to be explored even if you don't have a DX11 graphics card.

For further reading, click that link and scroll down halfway until you see D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain().